# Wrong parameters passed to tar command makes file1 unusable!

Tags: tar, posix

Wrong parameters passed to `tar` command makes `file1` unusable!!
Correct command to `tar` file is:

```
$ tar cvf total.tar file1 file2
```

but upon using the below format I am not able to recover `file1`

```
$ tar cvf file1 file2 total.tar
file2
tar: total.tar: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
$ ls -ltr
total 16
-rw-r----- 1      3 Apr 26 11:55 file2
-rw-r----- 1  10240 Apr 26 11:57 file1

$ file file1
file1: POSIX tar archive (GNU)


$ tar zxvf fil1
tar (child): fil1: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: You just overwrote `file1` with your incomplete `tar` archive.  It's now time to restore `file1` from your backups.

Answer (score 4):

You asked `tar` to archive the files `file2` and `total.tar` in the archive called `file1`, which it attempted to do. Unfortunately that means that `file1` was overwritten, all you can get from it now is `file2`:

```
tar tvf file1
```

(don't add a `z` in there, you didn't specify it when creating the archive).

The only way you'll recover `file1` is from backups.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation: The `f` in `cvf` is a shortcut for the `-f` option, which expects the name of the target file to tar to as next parameter. The outcome of switching the order of parameters has already been described by @AndrewHenle and @StephenKitt.

Answer (score -3):

This is a well known pitfall in the definition of the `tar command line syntax`.

The problem can be avoided by using my `star` instead.

`star` uses a different much less error sensible CLI definition when you call it under the name `star` and it is still much safer than the traditional tar implementation as it will not overwrite `plain files` when called as `tar`.

Comment: $ man star
No manual entry for star

Comment: If you are on a system with a friendly administrator, star should be installed, otherwise you may need to install star by your own. Either use the binary packages from your distro, or compile a recent version as included in the schilytools: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/index.html BTW: here is the man page: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html